# Why has this user's tantrum about a question they wanted deleted been successful?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, vandalism

[This heavily-downvoted semi-dupe](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/284111/) has been deleted after its author vandalized it several times and tried to vandalize the upvoted answer as well — mine, to be precise — apparently with the idea that "blank" = "deleted". [Deleting embarrassing questions at the request of their asker is explicitly not standard policy for ♦ moderators](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/).

But I'm not really sure why. I'm not entirely convinced it was a duplicate, and was planning to vote to reopen in a bit, and in any case even most heavily-downvoted dupes of frequently-asked requests aren't manually speedy-deleted — or deleted at all. And surely the appropriate response to self-vandalism of a question with a decent answer (-2/+10) is not to give in to the user and blow it away.

I didn't lose much with the deletion, just some meta rep — easy come, easy go — but for the same reason I rolled the question back from the first major replacement and answered it in the first place, I feel the current state is not really correct, and the question has a useful place on Meta to help people understand, if nothing else, the full range of loosely similar "comment + downvote" FRs that will get a sharply negative response from Meta.

Comment: It was deleted by a CM. I can only assume to stop drama.

Comment: @ChrisF not a valid reason. To stop drama they can, and should, lock the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Perhaps locking would have been a better option, but given the question it was duped against, it's probably not a great loss.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Realistically, you have to weigh the value of a question and its answers vs. the trouble it's causing, and sometimes it's just not worth the hassle to keep things around. Locks are generally only used in the most extreme cases.

Comment: @Brad not really. I've seen many questions being locked here on MSE, it's really not rare. That said, being a dupe is a strong point, so in this specific case guess deleting was indeed the best option. bluefeet explained it well in her answer. (after a small nudge :))

Comment: There's [not rare](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=locked%3A1+is%3Aquestion), and then there's [common](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1+locked%3A0+is%3Aquestion), @Shadow. (for those who can't run the latter search, there are about 140 times as many deleted questions here as there are locked questions.)

Comment: The question really should have been locked. That was a lot of unnecessary drama over, from what I could tell, absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Shog9 most of the questions I was talking about had only temporary lock, not permanent, and there is a good chance many of them were deleted anyway at some point, just not right away.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't know for sure, but I suspect the vast majority of the deleted questions were deleted for reasons entirely unrelated to tantrums, drama, rollbacks, comment wars, or other unpleasantness, so the numbers are entirely incomparable.

Comment: Your confidence in the respectability of Meta's past is gratifying, @nathan.

Comment: @Shog9: Well, I wouldn't be entirely surprised if there were in fact a lot of deleted, never-locked dramas. But 140 times as many? Not even slightly. That number just doesn't mean anything.

Comment: By the same token, there are plenty of other reasons to lock things. Regardless, if you're gonna argue for locking on the basis that it is not uncommon, deletion surely needs no more justification.

Comment: @Shog9: I argued against deletion on the basis of the FAQ. One of the [explicit purposes of locking](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229) is this exact scenario. I don't think more needs to be said: the one that was actually used is precisely the one that the FAQ says is not supposed to be used. Presumably the FAQ is wrong in one or both places.

Comment: The FAQ describes the purpose of locking, @Nathan - it doesn't mandate it. I've gotten into plenty of arguments (sometimes lasting months) over questions here that I felt were important enough to keep around even over the protests of their authors... But that certainly doesn't apply to *every* question. As a thought experiment, imagine if we militantly kept every single "why am I question-banned" post - at some point, they stop being signposts and start just being noise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There were no 20k users involved in the deletion of it, it was deleted by a member of the community team.

The post was causing a significant amount of drama, including 16 flags by the OP requesting deletion, rollback/edit wars. Since the post was closed as a duplicate it is sometimes much easier to delete it, than hand-hold it.  Your good answer could easily be added to any number of the duplicate posts regarding the issue in the question.

Comment: So why not locking it? There is a good answer, which its author spent time and efforts writing. Why let the troll win?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wasn't involved in the deletion, but I'm guessing it was for a variety of reasons - multiple flags including requests by the OP to remove the question, rollback wars, etc. and the fact that it was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Shadow A good answer that could easily be posted on one of the many duplicates we get about this issue all the time. Fighting the battle to keep this question simply isn't worth the effort.

Comment: @animuson and bluefeet those are good points, which are totally missing in the answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Updated to include a few more bits.